# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cal P(n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, prime-numbers

In an exercise I'm asked to evaluate the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cal P(n)}{n}$$
> Where $\cal P(n)$ is the number of prime numbers that devide $n$.

I have no idea how to approach this. I know that $1< \cal P(n) <n$ So this must mean that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\cal P(n)}{n} \in [0,1]$$

if the limit exists.

But I'm not able to find the exact value.

Comment: The function is also known as little $\omega$, more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function).

Comment: @rtybase The wording is ambiguous as to whether the function is $\omega$ or the with-multiplicity $\Omega$... doesn't affect the result anyway. Both grow even slower than the rate shown in my simple proof: they are asymptotically $\ln\ln n$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel <<Thereby $\omega (n)$ (little omega) counts each distinct prime factor>> vs <<$\cal P(n)$ is the number of prime numbers that devide $n$>>. Anyway, it was a comment for OP to let them know that the function is well known and pretty well studied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if $\mathcal P(n)$ counts prime factors *with multiplicity*, it's easy to show that $\mathcal P(n)\le\log_2n$. Take the prime factorisation $n=\prod_ip_i^{m_i}$ and replace all $p_i$ by $2$; since all primes are at least $2$ the product cannot increase, yielding $n\ge2^{\mathcal P(n)}$. Thus the limit expression is upper-bounded by $\frac{\log_2n}n$ and the limit is $0$.

Comment: How can we show that?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhaes I just added justification for the bound on $\mathcal P(n)$.

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães If you count with multiplicity, $$
n = p_1^{\alpha _1 }  \cdots p_k^{\alpha _k }  \ge 2^{\alpha _1 }  \cdots 2^{\alpha _k }  = 2^{\alpha _1  +  \cdots  + \alpha _k }  = 2^{\mathcal{P}(n)} .
$$

Comment: I get it now, thanks @Gary